# Google Sheets Pie Graph Aggregation Merges Completely Different Categories

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I've been trying to make a basic chart in google sheets that puts together the time taken for various activities to make a pie chart. Since the same activities appear multiple times I need to aggregate the data. However, it doesn't work in the way I would hope as it puts both the productive and unproductive categories under unproductive. I don't believe this is supposed to happen but I haven't seen anybody else have the same problem. It also should be noted that the unaggregated chart IS accurate to the data I fed in. It's only when I attempt aggregation and things don't work.

Graph without aggregation:

[image]

Graph with aggregation:

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Just for the record... these are NOT "Pie charts", they are "doughnut charts".

Comment: _it puts both the productive and unproductive categories under unproductive_ I tested using your simplified data, and my Aggregated graph includes both Productive and Nonproductive. It isn't possible for us to offer more detailed advice without seeing your data and knowing what data range was assigned to the "Aggregated" graph. Would you please edit your question to include your raw data, and describe the data range for your "with Aggregation" graph.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a doughnut chart from some data. In the first instance you do not aggregate the data. But when you do aggregate the data, the outcome is not as you expect - "Productive" data is included with "Unproductive" data.

I believe that you have a flaw in the way that you are designing your data and defining the Data Range for the Charts.

---

In both of the following example, the data range for each charts is "A1:B10".

As you can see, Productive time is included (and aggregated).

**Data and Charts**

[image: chart example]